# Can a constructor function also be called a function expression?

Tags: javascript

Is the only difference between them that an expression has some kind of logic inside it, while a constructor function only has a list of properties? I'm confused why there are separate names for seemingly the same thing..

```
 //this is an expression
 var myFunctionExpression = function(){console.log('hi')};

 //this is a constructor
 var myConstructorFunction = function(term){this.greeting = term;}
```

Comment: Yes, a "constructor" is identified mostly by its purpose, not by the syntax used to define it (function expression, function declaration, or even `class`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the only difference between them that an expression has some kind of logic inside it, while a constructor function only has a list of properties?

Not really.

The **function expression**:

```
var foo = function() { ... }
```

and the **function statement**:

```
function foo() {
   ...
}
```

are two different ways to define functions.

The **constructor function** is a special kind of functions that is supposed to create new instances of objects with the `new` operator. Inside this function you can use `this` to access to the instance it creates. Also, the function set its `prototype` as the prototype of the newly created instance.

A constructor function can be declared with a function expression

```
var Foo = function(whatever) {
   this.whatever = whatever;
} 

var f = new Foo(1);
// f.whatever = 1
```

or a function statement:

```
function Foo(whatever) {
   this.whatever = 1;
}

var f = new Foo();
// f.whatever = 1
```

Note however, that the constructor function doesn't necessarily set any properties (which contradicts yours *a constructor function only has a list of properties*) - this would be a perfectly valid constructor function:

```
  function Foo() {}
  var f = new Foo();
```

While this trivial example doesn't make much sense, introducing a prototype shows the real value:

```
  function Foo() {}
  Foo.prototype.bar = function() {}

  var f1 = new Foo();
  var f2 = new Foo();

  // both f1 and f2 have Foo.prototype as their prototype
  // both can call .bar() then
```

Comment: @Wiktor Thanks, there was a fire at my office about this question and you just put it out.